# Combining 2 arrays of the same distribution

Tags: statistics, distribution, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

If we have 2 arrays of the different size but having the same distribution, for example, uniform. And if we combine these 2 arrays in one array, will the new array still have uniform distribution?

Answer (score 0):

If the values in the two arrays are independent, yes.  From a distributional perspective it's indistinguishable from just increasing the sample size.